# Allow access to a folder except specific files and folders using a RewriteRule exception in Apache2

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm having issues redirecting a website at work to a new URL. The redirect of the site works just fine. An exception to the redirect works as well. The problem is that I need multiple exceptions. I need to redirect the entire site *except* the user directories and several other locations (a mix of entire folders and specific files.

Here's what I have (that works):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/~(.+) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.ca/department$1 [R=301,L]
```

It simply refuses to ignore these:

```
/somedir
/someotherdir/somefile.php
```

I've tried about every permutation of these with no success:

```
RewriteRule ^/someotherdir/somefile.php - [L]
and
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/someotherdir/somefile.php
```

Would someone be able to put me out of my misery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021722/mod-rewrite-with-exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

An Apache2 snippet from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021722/mod-rewrite-with-exceptions) has been modified as follows:

**Configuration**

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/somedir
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/someotherdir/somefile.php
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.ca/department$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

**Test results**

Some tests have been executed and the results are as follows:

<kbd>`Input`</kbd>                       <kbd>`Output`</kbd>                                    
<kbd>`IP`</kbd>                          <kbd>`http://www.domain.ca/department/`</kbd>          
<kbd>`IP/somedir`</kbd>                  <kbd>`IP/somedir`</kbd>                                
<kbd>`IP/someotherdir/somefile.php`</kbd><kbd>`IP/someotherdir/somefile.php`</kbd>              
<kbd>`IP/helloworld`</kbd>               <kbd>`http://www.domain.ca/department/helloworld`</kbd>